# Cannot cast from Map<String,Object> to Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>>

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am upgrading the following code:

```
return this.getMethod().execute(mp);
```

Where the execute method has signature:

```
public Map<String,Object> execute(Object mp)
```

I have code that expects the return of the method to be `Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>`, but the compiler is choking on the conversion. So can I / how do I get this to cast properly? And is there any change between Java 5 and 6 that would make this now a compile time issue?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "between 5 and 6"?

Comment: i think he meant java version

Comment: Can you guarantee the map's values will only be `List<Map<String, String>>`? Why did someone use generics, but then put `Object` as the value type?

Comment: I can guarantee (this code works in prod today) but I can't really change the interface because that is someone else's code and would take time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you're *sure* that the returned map will only contain values of type `List<Map<String, String>>`, then you need to use a double cast:

```
Map<String, Object> map = this.getMethod().execute(mp);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //thoroughly explain why it's okay here
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> mapWithNarrowedTypes =
        (Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>>)(Map<?, ?>)map;
return mapWithNarrowedTypes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Often for this type of problem I find useful the following construct:

```
public final class Reinterpret {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T cast(Object object) {
        return (T)object;
    }

}
```

Which you can use, e.g., like this:

```
...
public void process(Map<String, Object> data) {
    // method can properly handle any Object value,
    // including String
}

...
    Map<String, String> stringData = ...
    process(Reinterpret.<Map<String, Object>>cast(stringData));
...
```

As you can guess, that very precise weakening of Java generics type system was inspired by C++'s reinterpret_cast operator, and is applicable in similar contexts; however, it can also be used in a few others, such as when you want to reduce the verbosity of your casts, e.g.,

```
    Map<String, Object> objectMap = Reinterpret.cast(stringMap);
```

Java 6's type inference is strong enough (or weak enough, depending on your perspective) to cast the right-hand-side expression to what the left-hand-side requires; notice, however, that this works fine for assignments, but NOT for function calls, which is why the example above requires fully specifying the parametric types in the call itself.